# Simulink question about a electrotechnical system (simple autonomous vehicle)

Tags: motor, simulation, automotive, pid-controller, simulink

I am rather new to all the simulation work and its complex applications. I have been tasked to work on a rather complex project that is creating autonomous vehicle digital twin and then anayaize how different the outputs I get from the real vehicle's counterpart.

The vehicle is just a toy car that is remotely controlled.

In theory, this is the model of the car and how it should operate.

[image]

However, I am having tons of troubles and constant confusion on how to even start.

I am unable to figure out a way to provide GPS locations or pre set location to the model in order to get the desired outputs.

I do have the configs for both the State estimator and pid controller along with some of the needed information about the vehicle dynamics. Such as the yaw moment of inertia and 'wheel' size of the car and its mass, length and width.

However, I am having trouble working on the location and then also the outputs desired. The outputs I should get are as follows : X, Y out puts and their changes over time and how far are they from the desires location (cross track error).
I need the angular velocity, yaw angle and heading angle of the vehicle.

I know this is a lot to wrap one's head around. I'm just seeking anything to help start this or provide clarity on how to approach such problem in Simulink. I have been struggling with this for quite some time and I'm sure so stressed out not knowing what to do. Any help would be appreciated.